# GDAL libraries, who does what

Tags: python, ubuntu, gdal

I'm struggling installing GDAL on ubuntu 16.04 to work with GeoDjango (Django 2.1, python3), so I need to understand what I'm actually installing.

**What is the rôle of each library/package/module ?**

apt

- gdal-bin (A 'C' library containing the actual functions ?)
- python-gdal (The same in python, or just some kind of bridge ?)
- python3-gdal (see above, but for python3. Does it need python-gdal ?)

pip

- gdal
- pygdal

**What is the link between pip modules and apt packages here ?**

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're asking. I think you need to clarify.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear enough. Usually I only need to install pip modules for django. Now with geodjango, it needs some operating system wide library togeteher with pip module. So I'd like to understand how pygdal module "communicates" with say "python3-gdal" package. Why pygdal is not enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every piece of info is available, if one is willing to search for it.

- *DEB*s (installed system-wide):

  1. *gdal-bin* ([[Ubtu]: Package: gdal-bin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gdal-bin)) - a collection of *gdal* related binaries (tools and utilities)
  2. *python3-gdal* ([[Ubtu]: Package: python3-gdal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3-gdal)) - *Python **3*** bindings, extensions (*.so*s) and some wrapper scripts, which enable *gdal* usage from *Python*
  3. *python-gdal* - the same thing, but for *Python **2*** (totally unrelated to previous item)
- *WHL*s (installed as *Python* modules to the interpreter used to launch *pip*):

  4. *GDAL* ([[PyPI]: GDAL](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL)) - the sources (*.tar.gz*) for ***#2.*** (and / or ***#3.***). During `pip install` phase, they are built and installed for current *Python*
  5. *pygdal* ([[PyPI]: pygdal](https://pypi.org/project/pygdal)) - same thing (but for *VEnv*?) as previous item. It seems to be a lighter version (it doesn't contain the scripts)

But, **all of the above depend on *libgdal*** ([[Ubtu]: Package: libgdal1i](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libs/libgdal1i)), which is the ***gdal* library**.